# Is this a make bug?

Tags: makefile

Most likely it is not but I've been struggling with this one for an hour now:

```
$ cat Makefile
${FILE1}:
        touch $@

a: ${FILE1}

${FILE2}: a
        touch $@

$ make FILE1=foo FILE2=bar bar
touch foo
touch bar

$ ls
bar  foo  Makefile

$ make FILE1=foo FILE2=bar bar
touch bar
```

Why is the `bar` rule still activated?

If I change `Makefile` to:

```
${FILE1}:
        touch $@

${FILE2}: ${FILE1}
        touch $@
```

Everything works, i.e. `bar` is not touched again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The target `bar` has a prerequisite, `a`. You have a rule for `a`, but it does not actually build a file named "a". So every time you ask Make to rebuild `bar` (if necessary), Make sees that the prerequisite `a` does not exist, and therefore it must attempt to rebuild both targets.

Comment: That's what I thought as well. But when added `.PHONY: a` and it still insisted so I thought it's something else. Is there any workaround for this?

Comment: @MiroKropacek: Yes, more than one. You could eliminate the `a` rule, since it does nothing. Or you could introduce a dummy file, `a`. Maybe an order-only prerequisite would do, but that depends on what you're actually trying to do.